# Linq Select with Max/Min, Left Join

Tags: linq

I am trying to convert my program from ADO to Entity Framework and Linq. Can someone show me how to write this using Linq?

```
SELECT a.[Category], [WorkOrderVersion], min(a.[CategoryStartDate]) AS CategoryStartDate, 
       max(a.[CategoryEndDate]) AS CategoryEndDate, c.[HexColor] AS CustomBackgroundColor
FROM [Job].[EstimateTbl] as a
Left JOIN [Employee].[EmployeeColorPrefsTbl] c 
     ON c.[Item] = a.[Category] AND c.[EmployeeID] = @employeeID
Where [ID_Job] = @ID_Job 
group by [Category], [WorkOrderVersion], c.[HexColor] 
ORDER BY [Category]
```

I am close, but I'm not getting the grouping and Max/Min part...

```
var query = from a in db.EstimateTbls
            where a.ID_Job == objActiveJobClass.ID
            join c in db.EmployeeColorPrefsTbls on a.Category equals c.Item into ps
            from c in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
            orderby a.Category ascending
            select new
            {
             a.Category,
             a.WorkOrderDate,
             CategoryStartDate = a.CategoryStartDate,
             CategoryEndDate = a.CategoryEndDate,
             c.HexColor,
            };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query = (from a in db.EstimateTbls.Where(x=>x.ID_Job==objActiveJobClass.ID)
            join c in db.EmployeeColorPrefsTbls.Where(x=>x.EmployeeID==@employeeID)
                 on a.Category equals c.Item 
            into ps1
            from ps in ps1.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new{a,ps}).ToList()
            .GroupBy(x=>new{x.a.Category,x.a.WorkOrderVersion,HexColor=x.ps?.HexColor})
            .Select(x=>new
                       {
                        Category=x.Key.Category,
                        WorkOrderVersion=x.Select(z=>z.a.WorkOrderVersion).FirstOrDefault(),
                        CategoryStartDate=x.Min(z=>z.a.CategoryStartDate),
                        CategoryEndDate=x.Max(z=>z.a.CategoryEndDate),
                        CustomBackgroundColor=x.Key.HexColor
                       })
            .OrderBy(x=>x.Category)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks. I like the way you did this and would like to go through it, but I get a number of compile errors that I can't figure out how to change. "HexColor does not exist..., x cannot be defined in this scope..."

Comment: about `x` issue, by mistake `Category=x.x.Key.Category` it happenrd change it to `Category=x.Key.Category` and about `hexcolor` are you sure it exists in class `employeecolorpref`

Comment: HexColor does exist. I get an error for x at Select x. If it helps, my answer below does work, but yours has some interesting things I would like to better understand.

Comment: It's bracket buddy, it's a stupid mistake..`x.ps1.HexColor}`  in groupby should be `x.ps1.HexColor})`

Comment: One more thing the below answer won't fetch you the result which above mentioned `SQL` query will result in. I have converted the `SQL` into `LINQ`

Comment: Yes, that solved everything but the HexColor. It looks like when I hover over HexColor VS thinks it should come from "a."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176933/discussion-between-sumit-raj-and-mjordan).

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from a in db.EstimateTbls
                        where a.ID_Job == objActiveJobClass.ID
                        join c in db.EmployeeColorPrefsTbls on a.Category equals c.Item 
                        group new { a, c} by new { a.Category, a.WorkOrderVersion, a.CategoryStartDate, a.CategoryEndDate, c.HexColor } into g
                        orderby g.Key.Category ascending, g.Key.WorkOrderVersion
                        select new
                        {
                            Count = g.Count(),
                            g.Key.Category,
                            g.Key.WorkOrderVersion,
                            g.Key.CategoryStartDate,
                            g.Key.CategoryEndDate,
                            CustomBackgroundColor = g.Key.HexColor,

                        };
```

APP.1 (2) 7/26/2018 12:00:00 AM, 7/31/2018 12:00:00 AM, #FFFFA500

CAB.1 (6) , , #FF00FF00

CLN.1 (126) , , #FF7FFFD4

DMO.1 (5) 8/1/2018 12:00:00 AM, 8/5/2018 12:00:00 AM, #FFFF0000

DMO.2 (1) 8/5/2018 12:00:00 AM, 8/10/2018 12:00:00 AM, #FFFF0000